# Change color of specific text in files

Tags: font-lock

Was wondering if anyone knew of a way to go into the .emacs file and add an attribute to change the color of a specific string in all files it appears.  The specific example I wish to use this for would be for any given file, if the string "TODO" exists, make the color of that text red.  I want that string to stand out in my java, python, c++, etc. files so I can pick them out when easily looking around.

Comment: See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html) and [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockKeywords) on [adding](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords) font lock keywords.

Comment: What @Dan said. Use syntax-based (aka font-lock) highlighting, and add it via a mode hook. That will take care of any buffer in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

A quick example would be this, which adds the `font-lock-warning-face` to all regex matches in all modes that derive from prog-mode:

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(lambda ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords
        nil '(("\\<\\(FIX\\|TODO\\|FIXME\\|HACK\\|REFACTOR\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

Further reading with examples in the emacs wiki:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords

Comment: Should this work on Java files as well?

Comment: If the java-mode you use is derived from the prog-mode and calls the prog-mode-hook, then yes. Otherwise try to change the `'prog-mode-hook` to `'java-mode-hook`. If the `java-mode` is done well it should call this hook upon creation of the `java-mode` buffer.

Comment: Ok and the `'java-mode` is something that comes standard in emacs or that's something I would have to implement myself?

Comment: Emacs comes with `java-mode` -- if you just try opening a .java file it should be activated. Java mode does derive from `prog-mode` so the suggestion should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is specifically about TODO-style comments, there are various packages available from [MELPA](https://melpa.org) that provide highlighting and related commands such as jumping to the next/previous such comment.

For example:

- [`hl-todo`](https://github.com/tarsius/hl-todo)
- [`fixmee`](https://github.com/rolandwalker/fixmee)